# CSS animation not working in Internet Explorer, specifically IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-animations

Here's the code I'm working with. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Basically an automatic image slider. In IE I'm just getting the first img with no sliding.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<style type="text/css">
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

@-o-keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

@-ms-keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
  -webkit-animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
  -moz-animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
  -o-animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
  -ms-animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
</style>
<div id="slider">
<figure>
    <img alt="" src="#" />
    <img alt="" src="#" />
    <img alt="" src="#" />
    <img alt="" src="#" />
    <img alt="" src="http://static.lakana.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2016/05/24/5mayors300X100-black-border_1464108603276_8689483_ver1.0.jpg" />
</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: `@keyframes` wasn't supported [until IE10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#Browser_Compatibility)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see here, CSS Animations are not supported in IE9: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: "yet" is probably the wrong word. [IE < 11 is no longer supported by Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support).

Comment: @4castle even though your answer is not 100% correct (IE10 under Windows Server 2012 is still supported and even IE9 under Windows Vista until 2017), i agree, that Microsoft will probably not develop them further. Removed 'yet' :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the problem is having to use IE. If it's for a client you can tell them you can't make this work on legacy browsers, maybe display something in place of it (ideally a message to upgrade their browser)